# Populating HTML from MySQL & PDO (PHP); foreach loop failing to write MySQL data

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, pdo

As title states, my objective is to produce an HTML table using data from a MySQL database.

The general method I am using is sound, as I have written manually a series of cells, but I am trying to scale it to include large numbers of fields, and as such am trying to write the HTML for the cells using PHP and foreach loops with arrays. I've written out the context and steps of my working to both give context to my problem and provide general help to people in a similar situation. I know, however, that the problem I have lies specifically in one section of code - indicated clearly below if you want to skip right to it.

**Step 1 define arrays for the titles I'd like the fields to have and the column names in the MySQL db:**

```
$titles  = array('Name', 'Age', 'Height', 'Weight');
$headers = array('q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4');
```

**Step 2: connect to the database ($username and $password previously defined):**

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db01', $username, $password);
    $pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

**Step 3: Create my SQL statement via a few concatenations, and fetch the $result:**

```
$sql ="SELECT";

foreach(array_combine($headers, $titles) as $header => $title) {
    $sql .= "`$header` AS `$title`,";
}

$sql .= "`q5` AS `Eye Color`";
$sql .= "FROM samdata.CO_data";


$result = $pdo->query($sql);
```

**Step 4: Create $html_table by concatenating static HTML and the results from the above SQL query**

```
if($result !== false) {
    $html_table = '<table><tr>';
    foreach($titles as $title) {
        $html_table .= "<th> $title </th>";                          
    }

    $html_table .='</tr> <tr>';


//*********PROBLEM SECTION BELOW **************************
    foreach(array_combine($result, $titles) as $row => $title) {                            
        $html_table .= "<td>' .$row\['$title'\]. '</td>";
    }
}
//*********PROBLEM SECTION ABOVE **************************

$html_table .= '</tr> </table>';
$conn = null;   

echo $html_table;       
}
```

I know the problem lies with the section indicated, because I've test all the other parts, and if instead of combining arrays / foreach loops I manually write out, for example:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
             $html_table .= '
             <tr>
                <td>' .$row['Names']. '</td>
                <td>' .$row['Age']. '</td>
                <td>' .$row['Height']. '</td>
            </tr>';
}
```

In place of the loop, then it works fine and displays the data for each result for those headings, the problem being I have hundreds and want to be more elegant (and lazy) than writing them all out one by one!

Where am I going wrong? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you try changing this line `"<td>' .$row\['$title'\]. '</td>"`  to this  `"<td> .$row['$title']. </td>"`

Comment: Good idea - but no change unfortunately.

Comment: I just thought that the single quotes would prevent the code from being run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are not looping correctly. $result is a PDOStatement which you must fetch. Try

```
foreach( $result->fetchAll() as $row ) {
    $html_table .= '<tr>' . "\n";
    foreach( $row as $col ) {
        $html_table .= '<td>' .$col. '</td>';
    }
    $html_table .= '</tr>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I see, so $result is not an array, hence my loop failure. Thank you for this - your code is resulting in just one record being displayed rather than all of them however - I haven't got my head around what you are doing here quite, so not sure how to debug: any thoughts?

Comment: Additionally - something odd is happening: The one record I am getting is a selection of different fields from several records (Which I can see my looking at the table directly in MySQL workbench)

Comment: You need to loop the rows and then the cols. Just edited. try again.

Comment: My mind is blown :) Thanks so much, I've been working on this for hours - this works perfectly! For my understanding if you have time to explain, does $result->fetchAll() as $data take every result and turn it into an array called $data?. Also what is the \n?

Comment: PDOStatement::fetchAll() returns an array containing all of the remaining rows in the result set. Taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php . Cheers.

Comment: "\n" is the newline character.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have some mismatched quotes on your problem line:

```
$html_table .= "<td>' .$row\['$title'\]. '</td>";
```

You begin with a double quote. Inside double quotes, single quotes cannot be used to terminate the string. Instead, double quotes can only be terminated by double quotes. And the same goes for the single quotes. Meaning, this can be fixed in one of two ways:

```
$html_table .= "<td>" . $row[$title] . "</td>";
```

Or:

```
$html_table .= '<td>' . $row[$title] . '</td>';
```

Also notice how I removed the quotes from around `$title`. They are unnecessary and will make PHP do a little more processing than necessary.

Notice how the quotes match now. Be sure, when writing code in your editor, to look at how the syntax is highlighted. You should see that with your original code, the variable and index were inside the string, because it would all be the same color.

If you are relying on variable expansion in double-quoted strings (like `echo "Hello $name";`), know that accessing string keys of arrays will not work unless they are surrounded with brackets like so:

```
echo "Hello {$person['FirstName']}";
```

You can however, use numeric indices like so:

```
echo "Hello $people[0]";
```

So with your code, you'd need to do this if you didn't want to end the string and concatenate the value and then begin the string again:

```
$html_table .= "<td>{$row[$title]}</td>";
```

However, I find this syntax ugly and it makes PHP do extra processing to find the places where it needs to expand variables. IMHO, use concatenation to avoid all of these problems.

Comment: You don't want the variable name in single quotes, should be `$html_table .= "<td>" . $row[$title] . "</td>";` or `$html_table .= '<td>' . $row[$title] . '</td>';` or even `$html_table .= "<td>{$row[$title]}</td>";`

Comment: Thanks very much for this: detailed and educational! Looks like I have a problem that is a combination of this syntax error and looping oncorrectly as per another answer here - I'll adjust both. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

this solution seems to be working in my project and allows me to get the column from the query and the records into an html table, hopefully it might help someone else too:

```
$conn = (...)

$sqlselect = "SELECT name, last, othercol FROM persontable";

// I prepare and execute my query
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlselect);
$stmt->execute();

//get full recordset: header and records
$fullrs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

//get the first row (column headers) but do not go to next record
$colheaders = current($fullrs)

out = ""; //variable that will hold my table

out .= <table>;

//get my columns headers in the table          
foreach($colheaders as $key=>$val) 
{
    $out .= '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
}

//get my records in the table
foreach($fullrs as $row) 
{
   $out .= "<tr>"; 
      $out .= '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
      $out .= '<td>'.$row['last'].'</td>';
      $out .= '<td>'.$row['othercol'].'</td>';
   $out .= "</tr>";
}

out .= </table>;  

//spit my table out
echo $out;
```